# Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

Tags: json, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

```
{
    "type": "origins:damage_over_time",
    "interval": 40,
    "onset_delay": 1,
    "damage": 1,
    "damage_easy": 1,
    "source": {
        "name": "generic",
        "unblockable": true,
        "bypasses_armor": false
    },
    "condition": {
        "type": "origins:biome",
        "condition": {
            "type": "origins:temperature",
            "comparison": "<=",
            "compare_to": 0.5
        },
        "entity_condition": {
            "type": "origins:in_tag",
            "inverted": true,
            "equipment_slot": "mainhand",
            "item_condition": {
                "type": "origins:in_tag",
                "conditions": [{
                        "type": "minecraft:torch"
                    },
                    "type": "minecraft:lava_bucket",
                }
                "condition": {
                    "type": "origins:block_in_radius",
                    "inverted": true,
                    "block_condition": {
                        "type": "origins:in_tag",
                        "tag": "origins:lava"
                    },
                    "radius": 4,
                    "shape": "cube",
                    "comparison": ">=",
                    "compare_to": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"name": "Cold Blooded",
"description": "you can't generate heat, so you die slowly without a source of heat."
}
```

I've been trying to make an origin in Minecraft, like in the mod, but I'm having trouble with a part of the code, I put this in the JSON Validator, and it says the error above, the problem is in  "type: "minecraft:lava_bucket", can someone help me here?, oh and everyone can get the code if they want, is to take damage in cold biomes, except if you carry a torch or lava bucket

Comment: You have formatting errors in your `conditions` array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `conditions` array has this:

```
"conditions":
[
  {
    "type": "minecraft:torch"
  },
  "type": "minecraft:lava_bucket",      MISSING OPENING BRACE
  }                                     MISSING COMMA
  "condition":                          DO YOU REALLY WANT THIS HERE?
  {
    "type": "origins:block_in_radius",
    "inverted": true,
    "block_condition":
    {
      "type": "origins:in_tag",
      "tag": "origins:lava"
    },
    "radius": 4,
    "shape": "cube",
    "comparison": ">=",
    "compare_to": 1
  }
]
```

Assuming that array has 3 objects, you probably want to change it to this:

```
"conditions":
[
  {
    "type": "minecraft:torch"
  },
  {
    "type": "minecraft:lava_bucket",
  },
  {
    "type": "origins:block_in_radius",
    "inverted": true,
    "block_condition":
    {
      "type": "origins:in_tag",
      "tag": "origins:lava"
    },
    "radius": 4,
    "shape": "cube",
    "comparison": ">=",
    "compare_to": 1
  }
]
```

With the correction I suggested, you now appear to have an array with three conditions: 1) Torch, 2) Lava Bucket and 3) Lava within a radius. So if this is not doing what you would like. You must also have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I followed the code (well I copy-pasted), and I do take damage in cold biomes, but it don't stop when I hold the bucket of lava or the torch, not even when I'm near lava

Comment: I do not know exactly what you had intended so I made some assumptions. If you look at the 3 lines where I put BOLD comments, you can see where the JSON had errors. If you post the original JSON that you based yours on, perhaps I can see what needs to be changed.

Comment: well, I'm intending so whether you have a torch or a lava bucket in the main hand or you are near lava, you stop taking damage from the cold biomes, I actually copied this from another guy and tried to make some fixes, but I can't get the damage to stop when I'm holding the bucket, the torch or I'm near the lava